# Chunk event never fires in https request

Tags: node.js

I'm testing some calls to an API (Splunk).  When I do the call in curl, it works as expected.

```
curl -k -v -u admin:password -d 'search=search error | head 10' -d "output_mode=json"     https://192.168.50.16:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export
```

This works correctly and returns a body containing a json array of results.

But when I try to make the same request from my node app, I get no body.  In the code below, the on chunk event never fires.  No errors; request appears to go off correctly and I do get a 200 back with a header "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8".  So why no body/chunks?  Does the request method do something differently here than what curl would do?  As far as I can tell, these should be the exact same request.

While troubleshooting, I make a quick PHP script that just echo'd back the POST vars.  When I pointed this code at that script instead, it worked fine - I got chunks back with my PHP output.  So I'm left to try to figure out why the API might respond correctly to a request from curl, but not one from node.js.  Any thoughts?

```
    var https = require('https');
    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var data = { output_mode:'json', search: 'search error | head 10' };
    var datastring = querystring.stringify(data);

    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': datastring.length
    };

    var options = {
        hostname: '192.168.50.16',
        port: 8089,
        path: '/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export',
        method: 'POST',
        auth: 'admin:password',
        headers: headers
    };

    var theRequest = https.request(options, function(api_response) {
        var responsedata = '';
        api_response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('got a chunk');
            responsedata += chunk;
        });

        api_response.on('end', function () {
            callback(true, responsedata);
        });
    });

    theRequest.write(datastring);

    theRequest.end();
    theRequest.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. It makes working with http(s) much easier in node. Check out the example below and see if you get any response from the server

```
var request = require('request')
var postData = { output_mode:'json', search: 'search error | head 10' };

var options = {
    url: 'https://192.168.50.16:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
      user: 'admin',
      pass: 'password',
    },
    form: postData
};
var r = request(options, function(err, res, body) {
   if (err) {
      console.dir(err)
      return
   }
   console.dir('status code', res.statusCode)
   console.dir(body)
})
```

You can also pipe the request and listen to the data events

```
var options = ... // look above
var r = request(options)
r.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('request data received')
})
```